# How to "cat /etc/shadow" on an HMC?

Tags: users, password, accounts, ibm-hmc

```
hscroot@hmcserver:~> grep root /etc/group
root:x:0:hscroot,ccfw
hscroot@hmcserver:~> 
hscroot@hmcserver:~> ls -la /etc/shadow
-r-------- 1 root shadow 5252 2015-05-06 19:36 /etc/shadow
hscroot@hmcserver:~> 
hscroot@hmcserver:~> cat /etc/shadow
cat: /etc/shadow: Permission denied
hscroot@hmcserver:~> 
hscroot@hmcserver:~> grep hscroot /etc/passwd
hscroot:x:500:500:HMC Super User:/home/hscroot:/bin/hmcbash
hscroot@hmcserver:~> 
hscroot@hmcserver:~> echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
hscroot@hmcserver:~> 
hscroot@hmcserver:~> su -
bash: su: command not found
hscroot@hmcserver:~> sudo su -
bash: sudo: command not found
hscroot@hmcserver:~> bash
bash: bash: command not found
hscroot@hmcserver:~> chs
bash: chs: command not found
hscroot@hmcserver:~> ksh
bash: ksh: command not found
hscroot@hmcserver:~> ls /bin/bash
/bin/bash
hscroot@hmcserver:~> /bin/bash
bash: /bin/bash: restricted: cannot specify `/' in command names
hscroot@hmcserver:~> exit
exit
Connection to 1.2.3.4 closed.
[user@notebook ~]$ ssh hscroot@1.2.3.4 /bin/bash
Password: 
/bin/bash: /bin/bash: restricted: cannot specify `/' in command names
[user@notebook ~]$
```

**Question**: How can I cat the "**/etc/shadow**"? I only have "hscroot" user.

I have X forward if I use "ssh -X".

Comment: I may be wrong but I thought HMC was the systems management application for AIX. Is it OS neutral?

Comment: umm, yes and maybe yes.

Comment: Are you trying to recover the password on the HMC? I may have misunderstood the question at first.

Comment: I want to cat the /etc/shadow file. :\

Comment: The point of file permissions is that you can't unless you have appropriate privileges. You don't so you can't.

Comment: @Bratchley IBM pSeries HMC's are Intel/AMD boxes which run Linux, and are hardware management consoles for the pSeries hardware.  So the HMC stuff is technically a bunch of software just built on Linux, but the key element is that it runs a very restricted shell by default.

Comment: @EightBitTony just for my education, does that mean it only does hardware management and not OS-level management? If not. does AIX have something that fills that role?

Comment: @Bratchley The AIX system management tool is called SMIT.

Comment: Not just file permissions -- it's also a shell in restricted mode. If there a way to run arbitrary commands on it, that would be a security bug (and future versions would fix it).

Comment: @casey I was thinking something more along the lines of Katello or Spacewalk where you manage multiple servers and push out stuff like OS configuration updates.

Comment: @Bratchley the HMC is there to manage the hardware, create partitions (LPARs, Micropartitions, whatever you like to call them), allocate out hardware, provide hardware alerting, dial-home, remote console access, patch firmware etc.  You can do basic installs of PowerVM (VIOS) from the HMC, but no software management.  NIM is the standard product which allows you to install and patch multiple remote AIX systems, but it's not on the same scale as Katello or Spacewalk.

Comment: @EightBitTony fwiw I think I located what I was searching for with [IBM Systems Director](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/director/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You submit a support call to IBM who then give you the **hscpe** user password, which is good for one day.  That user ID and password allows you to gain access to root (assuming you recorded the root password when you installed the HMC).  Then you can `cat /etc/shadow`.

You can't do it without root access (by design), and you can't simply switch to root either (also by design) on an HMC.

Answer (score 2):

A HMC is a blackbox solution from IBM. You aren't supposed to have root access.
It is possible to request a tempoary password from IBM that provide root access.

Answer (score 1):

As a comment says, you don't `cat /etc/shadow` unless you already have root permissions. That's how the system is designed - that's how UNIX and Linux system have been designed since at least the 1990's if not before (pre-1992 is before my time, so I can't speak with authority).

Comment: In the dawn of time the password was in `/etc/passwd`, which was (and still is) world-readable. Hence the name, of course. Back then it seemed that the one-way encryption algorithm (use the password as the key to encrypt a constant string) was strong enough that there was no danger of brute-forcing. Eventually this was no longer a reasonable assumption, and since `/etc/passwd` is used to look up user names, the password was moved to a new unreadable location.

Comment: The [earliest versions of Linux didn't shadow passwords](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Shadow-Password-HOWTO-2.html).

Answer (score 0):

with hscroot you can do a:

```
chhmcusr -u root -t passwd
```

and thus you will now know (change) the root password, log in with root, cat the /etc/shadow. Then if needed, restore the old shadow file from backup, so the root pw will be unchanged, but you will still have a root terminal to cat.

But I didn't tested this yet. Usually "PermitRootLogin no" is in the sshd_config..